# How to place the config.rb for compass in a Directory above the css and scss files?

Tags: configuration, compass-sass

so I have

```
- [folder]
  + config.rb
  + [scss]
  + [js]
  + [img]
  + [css]
```

but I want to have

```
- [folder]
  + config.rb
  - [folder]
    - [folder] 
      + [scss]
      + [js]
      + [img]
      + [css]
```

I already tried the `project_path` variable but it didn't work. Any help would be great

Answer (score 2):

For this structure:

```
- deploy/
  + config.rb
  - public_html/
    - assets/ 
      - sass/
      - js/
      - img/
      - css/
```

Try this:

```
http_path = "public_html/"
sass_dir = "public_html/assets/sass"
css_dir = "public_html/assets/css"
images_dir = "public_html/assets/img"
javascripts_dir = "public_html/assets/js"
relative_assets = true
```